# Wiping windows, installing 17.10 from USB, but install always fails - HW check.

Tags: boot

I've run previous versions of Ubuntu on the bare metal of this system, and I've been running 17.10 inside VMs for a while without problems.

Decided to wipe the host OS and go for 17.10 for the long term, but my install always fails.

System config: 
Intel i7 965 
Intel x58 chipset (EVGA)
12GB DDR2 @ 1333mhz -- all banks tested ok. 
Nvidia 960 GPU

I have made 2 different Ubuntu 17.10 boot images on 2 different flash drives, both fail.

The failure occurs after the system boots successfully from the flash, and no matter which install options I try, I get:

Hardware error machine check exception 4, bank 5

(obviously not full text - I can capture more if I've missed anything pertinent)

I read that this can be because of various BIOS settings not being factory, etc, but my system is totally factory and all voltages, freqs, etc, are stock. This system has been stable for 10+ years. Should I try 16.04? Any advice would be super helpful, as I'm ready to dump M$ for good. Thank you!

Comment: I guess.. Ubuntu wont install on my chipset/CPU/something magical? Who knows. I read elsewhere online that I should be able to install on this platform, and all my hardware tests fine, so who knows. I guess Ubuntu wont be my desktop OS after all, other than inside VMs.